# Does Windows shell %ERRORLEVEL% variable have a character limit?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, error-handling, cmd

A Windows shell has an %ERRORLEVEL% variable that can be used to find the exit code of a process that has been run via the shell. I can therefore use this in a .bat file to obtain the exit code of an external script that I call from within the .bat file. I want to return richer error information from the process I'm calling (a stack trace in the first instance). I want to return this from a Python script that I'm running, which I can do using the Python 'traceback' module. Can I hold this in %ERRORLEVEL%? Is there any documentation for this variable?

Comment: The error level is the return **code** (aka: integer) of the program. Any message is an output on the error channel of the program but is not held in that variable.

Comment: Yes, and that value you pass to `exit` must be an integer, as Simon explained. A stack trace isn't an integer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that I can do e.g. exit(3) from Python and that this passes through an error code, however a full error message passed from Python is passed on the error channel and is therefore unavailable within %ERRORLEVEL%. I think the solution I need is to output the response from the script into an error.log. It looks like I'm limited by using a batch file. Powershell would provide more flexibility to handle error responses more flexibly

Comment: The information presented here is incomplete. The [GetExitCodeProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) function documentation specify that the ExitCode is a "DWORD 32-bits integer". This means that from cmd.exe point of view, an .exe program may return as `%ERRORLEVEL%` a value from -2147483648 to 2147483647 and you may test that with a C++ or assembler program, or via `exit /B value` command. I don't see any reason because _any_ .exe program that run under Windows could not return a similar range of values, unless it was written this way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%ERRORLEVEL%` returns the exit code of program i.e., *it is a integer value and does not have a character limit*. As mention in [wiki document for DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#DOS):

> In DOS terminology, an **`errorlevel`** is an integer exit code returned by an executable program or subroutine. Errorlevels typically range from 0 to 255.

The [Windows section of the same document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Windows) says:

> Windows uses 32-bit unsigned integers as exit codes, although the command interpreter treats them as signed.

Comment: @LotPings - Where on earth did you come up with that ? Not true! EXIT /B can return negative values, and they are reflected properly in %ERRORLEVEL%

Comment: @dbenham Looks like i tend to do some false assumptions when my localtime is 02 am. Sorry.

Comment: `%ERRORLEVEL%` is signed and not limited to 255. A Windows exit code is a 32-bit `DWORD`. Typically the error code itself is 16-bit (0-65535), which is the range for bare WinAPI error numbers. If present, the upper 16-bit word of an exit code is typically the severity and facility of an [`HRESULT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198) or [`NTSTATUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231200) code. Notably the upper word for a WinAPI error that's returned as an `HRESULT` is `0x8007`, which is negative as a signed value.

Comment: The same _wiki document_ specify: "Windows uses 32-bit signed integers as exit codes", and I think this question is about "Windows shell %ERRORLEVEL% variable", not the ancient DOS one-byte %errorlevel% value...

Comment: Thank You everyone for correcting me. Done little bit of research and updated the answer with the findings. Feel free to edit in case I missed anything :)

Comment: The last quote is talking about POSIX status codes that mix an 8-bit exit code with signal information. Windows doesn't even have signals (instead it has exceptions, asynchronous procedure calls, window messages, and ALPC messages). A Windows exit code could be any 32-bit integer, but it's often a standard error code such as a bare WinAPI error code, an `HRESULT`, or an `NTSTATUS` value.

Comment: For example, if you kill a console app with Ctrl+Break, then `%errorlevel%` is -1073741510, which is the `NTSTATUS` code `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` (0xC000013A). That it starts with 0xC clarifies that it's not an `HRESULT` code, so we know this indicates an error. An `HRESULT` that starts with `0x8` is an error, but for `NTSTATUS` that's just a warning (not successful, but not as severe as an error, e.g. `STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES`). It's rare for the Windows API to leak `NTSTATUS` codes into user mode, but seeing `HRESULT` codes is not uncommon.

Comment: Windows exit codes are actually *unsigned* 32-bit integers, except that the command interpreter treats them as signed.  I've updated the Wikipedia article accordingly.  --- I've also edited your answer, since you encouraged us to do so: I've updated that quote and removed the references eryksun mentions, since they're about Linux rather than Windows.

Comment: The exit code is unsigned. However, `HRESULT` and `NTSTATUS` are both signed `LONG` typedefs, so these codes are properly interpreted as signed values, e.g. as cast by the macros [`SUCCEEDED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687197) and [`NT_SUCCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565436). Thus cmd.exe handling them as signed values is fine. Bare Windows errors, and most other exit codes, are in the range of a 16-bit integer, which cmd.exe will always return as a non-negative value in `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for returning a string, you can't assign a string to `%ERRORLEVEL%`. There is documentation on `%ERRORLEVEL%` [here](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).

And you could try an environment variable- I don't code python, but I'm sure there's a way to do it in Python, and you can access them in Batch.

Also, if you know beforehand what errors will be thrown you can assign a number to each, and then exit with and have Batch output respectively. But that's boring and really unreadable, so you might not want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the lower limit for %ERRORLEVEL% is -2147483648, for example, batch file:

```
set /a ERRORLEVEL = -1
:LOOP
set /a ERRORLEVEL = ERRORLEVEL * 2
REM ERRORLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%
@pause
@Goto :LOOP
```

will output

```
REM ERRORLEVEL = -2147483648
```

before

```
REM ERRORLEVEL = 0
```

but the command

```
set /a ERRORLEVEL = -2147483648
```

returns
"Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision."

```
set /a ERRORLEVEL = -2147483647
```

works.

Comment: Don't set the `errorlevel` variable. By doing so, you disable the intended function of that system variable.