# Why main function cannot return a negative number?

Tags: c++

This might be a really simple question for some, but I'm new to C++ and hope someone can answer this for me.

I'm using this [online C++ compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler). Here's the simple code I'm running in it:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1- 2;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return x;
}
```

The output is:

```
-1

...Program finished with exit code 255
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

That really ponders me. Why would the `main()` function return 255 when the value of `x` is -1?

Doesn't `main()` return an `int` (not an `unsigned int`), so it should be able to return a negative number, right?

How does -1 get converted to 255? Something to do with an 8-bit variable? But isn't the `int` type 16-bit?

Comment: ***but isn't int type 16 bit?*** It's usually larger than that for a modern CPU. Although it may be 16 bit for micro controllers.

Comment: You might get your answer here: [Why do I get error 255 when returning -1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/why-do-i-get-error-255-when-returning-1)

Comment: The return type is indeed `int`, but on unix systems a programs return value is an unsigned 8 bit integer regardless, so 0 through 255.

Comment: try it on Windows and you'll get -1

Comment: @phuclv on Windows, a process's exit code is a 32bit unsigned int. See [`ExitProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) and [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess).

Comment: @RemyLebeau in cmd it's a signed 32-bit int. [`echo %errorlevel%` after `cmd /c "exit 4000000000"`returns -294967296](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149267/995714#comment51200906_5149267). *"Windows uses 32-bit unsigned integers as exit codes, although the command interpreter treats them as signed"* [Does Windows shell %ERRORLEVEL% variable have a character limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41153463/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to C language really. The operating system, or possibly just the C runtime (the small piece of the code which sets up things for your C program and actually calls *your* `main` function) limits exit code of the program to unsigned 8 bit number.

Very nearly all systems today use *two's complement* representation for negative numbers,  and then bit pattern for -1 is having all bits of the number to be 1. Doesn't matter how many bits, they are all set when value is -1.

The simplest way to convert an `int` to 8 bit number is to just take 8 lowest bits (which are now all 1 as per above), so you end up with binary number:

```
11111111
```

If interpreted as unsigned, then in decimal value of this happens to be 255 (as signed 8 bits it is still -1), which you can check with any calculator which supports binary (such as Windows 10 Calculator app when you switch it to Programmer mode).

---

Looking at this from the opposite direction: When trying to understand funny numbers related to computers or programming, it is often useful to convert them to binary. If you convert 255 to binary, you get 11111111, and then if you know binary numbers, you should realize this is -1 if interpreted as signed 8 bit number.